# If $a + b + c = 0$ prove that

Tags: summation, products

If $a + b + c = 0$, prove that

1)$$
\sum_{\text{cyc}}{\frac{4bc - a^2}{bc + 2a^2}} = 3
$$

2)$$
\prod_{\text{cyc}}{\frac{4bc - a^2}{bc + 2a^2}} = 1
$$

There is a solution that uses two cubic equations. First is of form $x^3+px-q=0$ that has the roots $a,b$ and $c$. After he is forming another cubic equation with the roots the components of the sum of the product. I can't figure out how they've come to the equation
$y^3-3y^2-3\frac{5p^3-27q^2}{4p^3+27q^2}y-1=0$

Comment: all the combinations:$\frac{4ac-b^2}{ac+2b^2}$ $\frac{4bc-a^2}{bc+2a^2}$ $\frac{4ab-c^2}{ab+2c^2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $\displaystyle x^3+px-q=0, abc=q, ab+bc+ca=p$

and $\displaystyle a^3+pa-q=0\ \ \ \ (1)\iff a^3=q-pa\ \ \ \ (2)$

Assuming $q\ne0,$
$\displaystyle y=\frac{4bc-a^2}{bc+2a^2}=\frac{4abc-a^3}{abc+2a^3}$

$\displaystyle y=\frac{4q-a^3}{q+2a^3}$

Express $a^3$ in terms of $y$ and compare the value of $a^3$ with that of $(2)$ to express $a$ in terms of $y$

Replace the value of $a$ in $(1)$